# How to check cost of derby(apache in-memory datadase)

Tags: sql, database, spring, derby, cost-based-optimizer

I am using memory database(derby) with spring framework.

I am using that with bunch of annotations and xml. It works nice, but I am not sure my SQL is good enough or needs some optimizations.

Is there anyway to check the cost of SQL with derby? 
(I already visited derby homepage, but I need more examples) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic techniques for measuring the performance of your SQL are documented here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tuning/index.html